# Cant logout users from site when they use connect via facebook

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook

Ok i made a code where i connect the user to my database and then i set as login to that user, if the email is already in the database i just Login the user...

The problem is logout button is not working.. i have tried.

```
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
```

On the Logout, but as soon as is redirected to the index page, (i think is loged in again)

how can i avoid this..

EDIT: i dont want the user to be loged out from facebook. just loged out from my site

This is my code.

```
<?php
if ($userId) {
 //
 // already logged? show some data
 $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);





 if (isset($userInfo['email']))

{ include "facebookregister.php"; } else { echo "no hay permisos de facebook"; }

} else {
 //
 // use javaascript api to open dialogue and perform
 // the facebook connect process by inserting the fb:login-button
 ?>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <fb:login-button scope='email,user_birthday'></fb:login-button>
 <?php
}
?>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId : <?=YOUR_APP_ID?>,
 status : true,
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true,
 });



FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // This is the callback if everything is ok
 window.location.reload();
 });
 };

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
```

And the logout.

```
function logout_action()
    {
        $srv_nms=BASE;
        $srv_nms=str_replace("http://","",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=str_replace("https://","",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=str_replace("www.","",$srv_nms);


        $srv_pats=$srv_nms;

        $srv_nms_arr=explode("/",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=$srv_nms_arr[0];


        $srv_pats=str_replace($srv_nms."/","",$srv_pats);


        setcookie(COOKIE_LOGINID,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
        setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
        setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);

    session_start(); 
session_destroy();

        header("Location: ".$this->make_url("user/login/l"));
        die;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use a cookie.  Upon logout, set a cookie telling you that the have requested logout.  Then on the main page, before grabbing data from facebook API, check for the cookie.  Obviously you would have to overwrite or expire the cookie upon login...but this should solve it for you.

Comment: Yep the script its already using cookies  setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms); the problem is  i dont understand this values.. also i think this COOKIE_USERNAME is defined somewhere else.. i tried normal set and it dosent work... I will search for a tutorial on setting cookies thanks

Comment: You don't have to over-think it.  While not as "elegant"...don't worry with the cookies already in use...make a new one for this specific purpose.  Just set a cookie called "fblogout" (for example)...and set the value to "yes" or something.  Then you can just check to see if $_COOKIE['fblogout']=='yes' and bypass the facebook API.  Upon login, just set the expiration on that cookie to '-1' and it will go away (though I also would set the value to 'no' as a backup precaution).

Answer (score 0):

in logout action you are logging out by session_destroy which will clear session in your server only, not in api.

so you need make $facebook->api   logout request to logout from facebook completly.
NOTE: refer api documentation for logout request.

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to avoid... I dont want to logout the user from facebook, just for my site.. but this code creates kind of "loop", they are always logeid in again when they logout... can i set a name to fb:login like name="" or something to condition the "login" process.